# How to convert private variables from ReactJS to TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert ReactJS code to TypeScript and I stumbled upon code in React where private variables are being declared. But when I convert the .jsx file to .tsx, I'm getting errors such as

> Property '_element' does not exist on type 'SampleCode'.ts(2339)

Here is the snippet from ReactJS that I'm trying to convert.

```
export class SampleCode extends ParentCode{
    constructor(domElement: HTMLElement){
         super();
         this._element = domElement;
         this._d3SvgContainer = d3.select(this._element).append('svg');
    }
 }
```

This is only a part of the code, but I guess it's sufficient to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define them in the body of the class.

```
export class SampleCode extends ParentCode{

    private _element;
    private _d3SvgContainer;

    constructor(domElement: HTMLElement){
         super();
         this._element = domElement;
         this._d3SvgContainer = d3.select(this._element).append('svg');
    }
 }
```

Comment: How about type setting?

Comment: depends on the types:


private _element :any;
private _d3SvgContainer: any;


will work (depends on how strict your linter is). But you can dig inside the HTMLElement interface to see the actual types of those elements.

Comment: Seems fair, Thank you!

Comment: In case this helps: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlelement.html _element will be of type HTMLElement, _d3SvgContainer depends on what c3 returns (sorry, not familiar with the lib types)